CodeIgniter4 How to get GET parameter value only
So I've been reading the documentation and all I got:
$uri = current_url(true);
$query = $uri->getQuery();

The result is only the query string like:
id1=val1&id2=val2

I want to get id2 value. Using:
echo $uri->getQuery(['only' => ['id2']]);

I got:
id2=val2

Is there any way to get only the val2 string? Or I need to explode it myself?

I think you will have to split it yourself unfortunately. There is no such option as the CI4 getQuery()  code is based on the native http_build_query php method. https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/URI.php

BTW, you could of course use the getGet() method if you are working on the current url.
